# Modular arthimetic equation with multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Given

(−414×−916)mod12=Y

Identify which one of the following options does NOT give an equivalent expression to that above ?

0

(6+8)mod12

48 mod 12

14 mod 12

I expanded the brackets so

1) -414 * -916 = 379224

379224/12 = 31602

31602 x 12 +0

A  = 0 x 12 + 0 (?) I thought it wasnt this answer cos there was no mod in it...

B (6+8) mod 12

= 14/12 = 1 x 12 +2

C 48 mod 12 = 4 x 12 +0

D 14 mod 12 = 1 x 12 +2

1) I am confused as to the difference between B and D

D is stated as the right answer...but I am unsure why

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$(-414)\cdot(-916)=379224=12\cdot 31602$$

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate please?

Reading what you have written would suggest to me, implies that the remainder is 0, because the quotient integer is multipled precisely by virtue of the mod.

Using that logic (which I am not entirely sure is correct for the record)  I would then assume that by virtue of that, A and C are therefore nullified, which leaves us with B and D remaining.....?

Or is your hint directed towards my confusion as to the difference between B and D....?